# Laravel: Call to a member function parameters() on a non-object on Router.php

Tags: php, laravel

This is a weird I just get the following error without any proper stack trace. Any ideas how to decipher the root cause here?

> production.ERROR: exception
>   'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message
>   'Call to a member function parameters() on a non-object' in
>   /var/www/mobiletopshou/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1034

Comment: You'll need to provide more information than this. Like what code is being executed for the particular request that is throwing the exception: route definition for that particular URL with the executed code (closure or controller action).

Comment: @Bogdan thats the problem , only the this part of error gets logged into the log file:
production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to a member function parameters() on a non-object' in /var/www/mobiletopshou/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1034
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
#1 {main} [] []

Comment: I understand that, but based on that short exception there's no way to determine the issue. You need to track this manually by checking the code being executed by that request and see where it cracks, either through a process of elimination or by using a debugger. In either case, I can't help unless you share your code.

Comment: Also you can enable debug mode in Laravel, that should spit out the entire stack trace right in the browser.

Comment: As it looks like you have some problems with your routes, please post what is inside '/app/Http/routes.php' file.

Comment: @Bogdan The problem is that the app is an API itself so all the request are coming through the mobile client, so any route is not directly accessible through the browser directly. And even if I enable it I dont know which route is causing this problem.

Comment: @Shota the route file is quite big.. but any idea what route it could possible be GET or POST ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem by commenting `\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class` in HTTP Kernel (`App/Http/Kernel.php`).

Comment: This solves my problem too, but can you please explain me why it is working

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your comment. Anyway I didn't kwow what was the reason.